# delegate does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

I have a `tableview` ,and in that `tableview` i am setting `customcell` .in that `customcell` have a button,when button click then delegate method called and play or pause audio.
But i dont know why my method does not called.

here is my code.

AudioInfoCell.h   //itas child view

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol PlayPauseDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)playPauseAudio;

@end

@interface AudioInfoCell : UITableViewCell

{
    id<PlayPauseDelegate> delegate;

}

@property(nonatomic,strong)id delegate;

@end;
```

AudioInfoCell.m

```
@synthesize delegate;




- (IBAction)playPauseBtnTapped:(id)sender {

if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(playPauseAudio)])
{
    //send the delegate function with the amount entered by the user
    [delegate playPauseAudio];
}
}
```

AudioTableViewController.h   //its parent view

```
#import "AudioInfoCell.h"

@interface AudioTableViewController : UIViewController<PlayPauseDelegate>
```

AudioTableViewController.m

```
cell.delegate = self;

-(void)playPauseAudio{
NSLog(@"button pressed");
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the cell's delegate?

Comment: @Moxy can you specify what cell's delegate. if you talking about PlayPauseDelegate then i have seted it in AudioTableViewController.

Comment: and protocol of PlayPauseDelegate is in AudioinfoCell.

Comment: Just to remove any ambiguity, I'm not asking where you implemented the delegate's method but where you set the cell.delegate = "something";

Comment: @moxy i have seted cell.delegate = self; in AudioTableVieController, but still its not working.

Comment: Did you add the target/ action to your button?

Comment: yes butoon have IBOutlted method.which call delegate method,see in audioinfocell.m

Comment: You're messing with the protocols, as much I think the flow is wrong.First of all you need instead of retaining, you should assign and the other thing is that as well as my query is that on clicking of a button as present in tableview how you give call to your delegate? One more thing is the working of every button is same? M asking as you obsolete sender part so you can demarcated....

Comment: @Mohit_Jaiswal Dilip's answer have done the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kartik , i you have not specified in which method you have specifies `cell.delegate=self;` .

so i assume that you have specified it in `viewDidLoad`,instead of that specify it in `vieWillApear` method than it should work.